# php cookie not rewrite the new value

Tags: php, cookies

Good morning,

I've got such problem. I would like to store in cookies language, which user will choose. The value in local variable is still changed, but value in cookie is always the same. Even if I always delete the cookie and then I create it again the value stored in cookie is wrong and my local is good. Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['lng'])) {
    $lng = $_GET['lng'];
    if (($lng != "en") && ($lng != "de")) {
        $lng = "en";
    }
} else {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
        $lng = "en";
    } else {
        
        $lng = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }
    
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie("lang", $_COOKIE['lang'], time()-10); //here I try to remove cookie and then create another
}
setcookie("lang", $lng, time()+5);
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo $lng;

?>
```

print_r will allways return me the main language (en), even if in variable $lng there is de. I think, there will be just stupid problem, but I can't fix it. This removing line (which I commented) is there because of problem written on official php site:

> Be careful of using the same cookie name in subdirectories. Setting a simple cookie
>
> setcookie("region", $_GET['set_region']);
>
> both in the root / and for instance in this case /admin/ will create 2 cookies with different paths. In reading the cookies back only the first one is read regardless of path.

And I thought I've similar problem. But this didn't fix my problem and even when the cookie after 5 second will expire to cookie is then written again the bad "en" value.

Thank for your answer

Comment: Cookie will be visible in next request, not in current.

Comment: As far as I know, cookie expire time is related to client. It is impossible work with a so little difference, between server and  client, if they are not synchronized.

Comment: I tried to make more requests.. results are the same... here is what I get when no cookie is active:
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 5tgdg6l383av0jkqbr7mnfpfe4 ) de , where de is $lng

Array ( [lang] => en [PHPSESSID] => 5tgdg6l383av0jkqbr7mnfpfe4 ) here is my next result when cookies are active

Comment: If your cookies expire too soon, keep them in a cool place outside direct sunlight in a sealed container ( :P )

Comment: This code and 5 second I've got only because of tests... problem is absolutely different, that data in Cookie aren't changed

Comment: Have you really understood what the first comment by @ElonThan means? (Asking to make sure, because it doesn’t seem so.)

Comment: And besides that, storing the language in which to display the website(?) in a cookie is not a good approach – because search engine robots don’t use cookies. The info, which language is displayed, should be part of the URL – that gives robots the chance to index them individually, and also link users to specific language version of your page. With using cookies to store that info, all these advantages are lost to you.

Comment: I have it as part of URL (this $_GET variables), but I also store it in cookies, because I want to remember which language user had at last visit... is it wrong approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, it works for me.
I edited the code a bit, sorry for obfuscating it with one line if-statements.

I also set the cookie time to 1 day so it won't disappear when testing the code.

And remember, you have to update the page to read the new cookie, it will be one step behind `$lng`.

```
<?php

$allowed = array('en', 'de');
$chosen = $_GET['lng'] ? $_GET['lng'] : ($_COOKIE['lang'] ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : 'en');
$lng = in_array($chosen, $allowed) ? $chosen : 'en';

setcookie("lang", $lng, time()+24*60*60, '/');

var_dump($_COOKIE['lang']);
echo $lng;

?>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, main problem was, that in my code the cookies was stored always in different directory, that's why I didn't see the change... mainly the fourth parameter (the '/') saved it all... Thank you!